# Counting bytes of file online while reading it

Tags: c++, wininet

I'm trying to create a basic "Login" system with C++ console. Using PHP to confirm the user information, and C++ will simply retrieve the data the PHP file outputs.

I need the C++ code to read to the end of the file online and stop. The code I'm using counts extra bytes at the end of the file.

int main(){

```
HINTERNET connect = InternetOpenA("LoginCheckUserAgent 0.0.1v (compatible; harmless;)", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PRECONFIG, NULL, NULL, 0);

if (!connect){
    cout << "Connection Failed or Syntax error";
    return 0;
}

HINTERNET OpenAddress = InternetOpenUrlA(connect, "http://localhost/login/check.php?username=admin&password=admin", NULL, 0, INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION, 0);

if (!OpenAddress)
{
    DWORD ErrorNum = GetLastError();
    cout << "Failed to open URL \nError No: " << ErrorNum;
    InternetCloseHandle(connect);
    return 0;
}

char DataReceived[4096];
DWORD NumberOfBytesRead = 0;
while (InternetReadFile(OpenAddress, DataReceived, 4096, &NumberOfBytesRead) && NumberOfBytesRead)
{
    cout << DataReceived;
}

InternetCloseHandle(OpenAddress);
InternetCloseHandle(connect);

cin.get();
return 0;
```

}

Code above gives me: abc123|||||||||||etc.. (Until it hits 4096 bytes)
I want it to give me: abc123
I need to read the content of "http://localhost/login/check.php?username=admin&password=admin" exactly with no extra bytes. The code I provided tries reading 4096 bytes.

I know I could just set the 4096 to 1 or something, and only use the PHP to reply with 1 byte. But I want to have the PHP script respond with data that will always be changing so I can't just assume the number of bytes i'm going go be dealing with.

I don't need anyone to fix the code, I just want to know how I can go about determining the bytes I'm going to be reading, and then having my script read it to the end of those bytes. So I don't get unneeded bytes.

Sorry If I made anything confusing.

Comment: what do you think `NumberOfBytesRead` stores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of bytes you've actually read is in `NumberOfBytesRead`. So, to terminate your string, you just need to write a `\0` to that location in your array:

```
DataReceived[NumberofBytesRead] = '\0';
```

So right now, it's making *room* to read 4096 bytes, but of course only reads as many as were sent. The `NumberOfBytesRead` tells you how many bytes were *actually* read, rather than the number you requested.

Note: depending on the situation, a transmission might be broken up into pieces, so even if data was sent in a single "chunk", it might be received in several consecutive read attempts.

Typically you want to prefix your data with its length, so you can read (say) a 4-byte header telling you the length of the remainder, and know to keep reading until you've received the whole thing (or give up, such as if it's taking too long).